# How to access to ConnectionString from IConfiguration injected to controller in asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an AspnetCore project with this appsetting.json file:

```
{
   "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
   "ConectionStrings": {
     "DB": "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=ENIAC"
   }
}
```

Now I am getting this setting and inject that to my controller with this code:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

and in my controller I am trying access to connection String using this code:

```
public HomeController(IConfiguration _config) {
    config = _config;
    var t = config.GetConnectionString("DB");
    Debug.WriteLine(t);
}
```

but `t` is null now.

where is my mistake? how can i resove this issue?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to inject a configuration variable into a controller? Even more so, why do you want to inject what's required for a dependency such as a connection string? The actual problem is a typo though (`ConectionStrings` != `ConnectionStrings`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your appsettings.json file: `ConectionStrings` should be `ConnectionStrings`.